# Google Analytics 4 is summing sessions incorrectly - why?

Tags: google-analytics, sum, google-analytics-4

On GA4 when viewing the number of sessions, the summed number is different from the sum of each individual row. Image attached for clarity.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3oTs.png)

You can see that it says 35,626 total sessions at the top in the summary row, but if you actually sum the sessions shown it should be 35,959. Why is there a discrepancy?

Answer (score 1):

it's not a problem of counting neither servers. It's a different way to think.

If a user comes on Monday and Tuesday, then you'll have a user for each day on GA4. But on the global period, you'll have only 1. That explains the difference between the total and the sum, which makes the sum greater than the total.

There are also cases when the sum is inferior than the total. This is usually caused by thresholding and Google Signals.

Answer (score 0):

Because the main idea behind GA4 is for Google to save money on servers dedicated to supporting Analytics. Frankly, GA UA used to be too good for a free product.

GA4 comes in with a lot harsher data retention rules, dimensions cardinality limitations, stricter sampling and so on.

Now back to your question, given that a session can have only one channel associated, the difference in numbers may be a result of hyperloglog-like optimization of data aggregation. In other words, plain simple summing might be too expensive for GA4 to conduct in that report, so it uses advanced algorithms that do sums faster, but less accurate.

Besides, GA4 interface is known for its bugs.

Now if you want to fix that, a good option is to conduct your analytics in a BQ export from GA4 or in a BI tool of your choice on top of the exported data.

Comment: Is there any proof for this statement?

Comment: for which statement?

Comment: "the main idea behind GA4 is for Google to save money on servers dedicated to supporting Analytics".

Comment: Of course, Google won't tell you that it's what they were after largely. You can also check their pros for GA4 and notice that they're really nonsensical when you see what they mean. At this point it's a consensus amongst senior analysts whether technical or not that GA4 is an inferior product that's obviously and very predictably way cheaper in maintenance both in memory and processing. They did spend some effort on trying to bring a better interface and they underinvested. It's bugged even now. Gtag.js and Firebase's data structure are the only superior things, but they're not new.

Comment: can you please point me to whereabouts I can find these consensus? Good for next pitching

Comment: Measure Slack...

Answer (score 0):

I've created a custom report that shows active and total users per day, as well as a sum of each one.
The sum of active users for 1 month for me was around 71k. When I sum up all the days that make up active users I arrive at 89k.
I also haven't been able to find clarification on this.

My solution is to rely on summing up the individual days and trust that number compared to the automatic sum GA gives me.

If you create a report like this and restrict it to 1 day at a time, the sum will be correct as GA only has to sum based on 1 day I suppose. As soon as you add 2 days or more, the total sum becomes incorrect (or at least different)

This is only a problem for active and total users, not new users.
This leads me to believe that active and total users somehow only takes unique visitors into account when doing it's final sum.
[image: GA-custom-report]